# How to slide picture menu as marquee

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, marquee

I want to move some Images right to left as seen in [songspk.name](http://songspk.name). If you visit, you can see there is a group of pictures(6 nos) moving right to left, you can say them as marquee. But my question is there is no gap in between the pictures any where! If I use marquee to some pictures, till the last picture in not finished the first picture is not displaying again.. There is a long gap between last and first picture. My website can be seen at: [masti2k14.tk](http://www.masti2k14.tk)

I have used the following simple html marquee code. Please check its working on my site(masti2k14).

```
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" onmouseover="this.stop()" onmouseout="this.start()" >
<img src="/img/600195/600195910_9d9763a3a4.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="Natural"/>
<a href="site_94.xhtml"><img src="/img/600195/600195909_3514f40fb9.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="Grand Masti Songs"/></a>
<a href="site_39.xhtml"><img src="/img/600195/600195908_23b3ada634.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="Dhoom : 3 Songs"/></a>
<a href="site_63.xhtml"><img src="/img/600195/600195907_3f035091f2.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="Chennai Express Songs"/></a>
<a href="site_11.xhtml"><img src="/img/600195/600195906_2a818232d5.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="Aashiqui 2 Songs"/></a>
</marquee>
```

I want the picture or images shouldn't end to finish. There is a long gap between last and first picture/image.

Comment: Please give a code example and show what you tried until now. Also make sure you tage your question with the programming language/environmen you are using.

Comment: I just want to advice to choose other way, becouse showing images with slow animation and without progress or ability for user to have control and see all images, looks wrong, once <blink> looked good too...

Answer (score 1):

you can use jQuery and Marquee Plugin.

http://www.jqueryscript.net/animation/jQuery-Endless-Div-Scroll-Plugin.html

by the way.
`<marquee>` tag is deprecated.

**EDIT**

If you don't want to use any script like jQuery, check this fiddle by Chris Coyier.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chriscoyier/Hyg3C/20/)

Comment: Can you please make a code for me? HTML and CSS is preferred! For javascript the external javascript file is not supported in wapka.

Comment: I have a .js file. Bt couldn't host it anywhere. Can you help me so that I can use as '<script src="***.js">'

Comment: You don't need hosting to use Javascript. Just place a script tag on your HTML with the javascript as contents. And I don't beleive @a_enriquez will "make code" for you. The purpose of this site is learing, and it's pretty much common sense that copy-pasting does not help on this matter. You might ask a new question about your doubts with using jQuery or the marquee plugin, but users will be very hesitant to "give" you code that you can just paste on your system and work. Also, googling isn't against the law (unless you live in north Korea).

Comment: user3252226 if you prefer html and css, you can also search for css3 marquee. but it only supports modern browsers.

Just like @Kroltan said, " googling isn't against the law "

Comment: @user3252226 I updated the answer. please check it out.

Comment: Sorry, you have used while(): that is out of my understand as well as the images are not animating.

Answer (score 0):

try this. i havent tested it at all. it might work or not work. i know u said u can't do javascript, but the marquee tag is old as dirt. no one uses it anymore.

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="/img/600195/600195910_9d9763a3a4.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="Natural"/>
    <a href="site_94.xhtml"><img src="/img/600195/600195909_3514f40fb9.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="Grand Masti Songs"/></a>
    <a href="site_39.xhtml"><img src="/img/600195/600195908_23b3ada634.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="Dhoom : 3 Songs"/></a>
    <a href="site_63.xhtml"><img src="/img/600195/600195907_3f035091f2.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="Chennai Express Songs"/></a>
    <a href="site_11.xhtml"><img src="/img/600195/600195906_2a818232d5.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="Aashiqui 2 Songs"/></a>
    </div>

    .container
    {
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    }

    .container img
    {
    float:left;
    }



    while($('.container').attr('left') > 10)
    {
    $('.container').animate({marginLeft:'-=10px'},150,function() {});
    }
```